# Query not returning results when a "WHERE" condition is added to it

Tags: php, mysql

The query below is not returning any results.  I have copied it from a query that was working and the only thing different is the addition of the following condition:

> WHERE submissionid=$submissionid

Any ideas why this query is not returning any results?

```
$sqlStr2 = "SELECT 
                s.loginid
                ,s.title
                ,s.url
                ,s.displayurl
                ,s.datesubmitted
                ,l.username
                ,s.submissionid
                ,COUNT(c.commentid) countComments
             FROM submission s
            INNER JOIN login l ON s.loginid = l.loginid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN comment c ON s.submissionid = c.submissionid
              GROUP BY s.submissionid
             WHERE submissionid=$submissionid
             ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC
             LIMIT 10";

$tzFrom2 = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'); 
$tzTo2 = new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'); 

$result2 = mysql_query($sqlStr2);

$arr2 = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 
    $dt2 = new DateTime($row2["datesubmitted"], $tzFrom2); 
    $dt2->setTimezone($tzTo2);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row2["url"].'" TARGET="_blank">'.$row2["title"].'</a>  <div class="dispurl">'.$row2["displayurl"].'</div></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2name">Submitted by <a href="http://www...com/.../members/index.php?profile='.$row2["username"].'">'.$row2["username"].'</a> on '.$dt2->format('F j, Y &\nb\sp &\nb\sp g:i a').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www...com/.../comments/index.php?submissionid='.$row2["submissionid"].'">'.$row2["countComments"].' comments</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: The less effort it takes to read your code, the easier & faster it is for us to help.  Pls don't use tab formatting in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There is `c.submissionid` and `s.submissionid` -- maybe You should state in Your query which one You want to use. Example: `WHERE s.submissionid=$submissionid`
- I think `GROUP BY` should go after `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 4):

Just a hunch, but are you sure there are any rows that meet the condition?

```
WHERE submissionid=$submissionid
```

Also, have you checked the value of $submissionid to make sure you know what is in it when the query returns no rows?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

$result2 = mysql_query($sqlStrt2) or die("Error " . mysql_error());

To see if there is a problem with the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use php but it looks like it might not be filling in the variable. So maybe do:

```
WHERE submissionid=".$submissionid."
```

Just to be sure print out `$sqlStr2` to see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

your query `$sqlStr2` is not quieted.it's be usefully quiet all fisrt and i guess this `WHERE submissionid=$submissionid` should like this `WHERE submissionid=\'$submissionid\`'.

Comment: Escaping the quotes are not necessary because the wrapping quotes are double quotes, not single ones.

Comment: i had practice with this quotes, and a query can be rejected without  quotes, especially if it's digital.